# Android: Application is crashing on phone but on emulator works when I'm trying to open a web page

Tags: java, android

First of all I can't connect my Galaxy s2 Android 4.0.3 connect with my PC, eclipse doesn't find as a device so I must compile and copy to my memory card and I'm installing it on the phone. I'm compiling in debug mode. This would be the problem? Secondly, I'm using API Level 10 (Gingerbread 2.3.3) to develop the app.

What the application does?

The app. is having two EditText for (username and password) and a submit button. When the person has submitted the "form" I'm connecting to a web page and I verify if the username and the password given by the person is valid. If it's valid then the person is forced to open a web page. Here is crashing the app. The phone display becomes dark and after 10-15 seconds I'm getting an alert saying "The app is crashed". On emulator everything works fine.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
   //...
   if( checkUser(strUsername, strPassword) ){
      Intent browserInt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mydomain.com"));
      startActivity(browserInt);
   }
}

private boolean checkUser(String user, String pass){

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet req = new HttpGet("http://mydomain.com/login.php?u="+user+"&p="+pass+"");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(req);

            String html = "";
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                html += line;
            }

            reader.close();
            in.close();

            if(html == null || html.length() < 5) return false;

            String[] temp1 = html.split("<body>");
            String[] temp2 = temp1[1].split("</body>");

            if(!temp2[0].equals("correct")) return false;

            return true;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**SOLUTION**
I started CMD and typed the path (where adb.exe is). In my case:

> D:/eclipse android/5.sdk/sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe

Then I set DEBUG enabled in my settings and plugged the USB to my PC. Then I entered this command in CMD:

> adb.exe start-server

Then I checked if my device (my phone) is attached:

> adb.exe devices

And there he was. I entered eclipse and run the application.

Comment: Can you add the crash itself? logcat?

Comment: I can't on the emulator works fine. It's crashing on the phone.

Comment: You can connect the phone to the computer and using the ADB analyze the logcat. Or you can use some log reporter such as http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Answer (score 0):

Download Samsung Kies [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Telephony-SMS-GSM/Kies.shtml), this will install a driver for your device, and adb will then connect to your device and you will be able to see the erroe in LogCat.
By the description of your error it seems that your network connection on the real device is slow/unstable, check that it is OK, and then try again. 
And please post the error log, when you get a connection to the device.

Comment: I have installed Samsung Kies, the software is seeing my phone I can transfer data, but I can't connect via ADB and eclipse as well. When I'm running adb.exe with CMD and I'm typing: adb.exe devices, it returns me nothing. It's saying that no device is attached.

Comment: Have you checked the settings? There must be a option somewhere to turn on USB debugging.

Comment: Thank you guys, now it's working. Samsung Kies helps me only if I wanted Mass Storage. I have edited my post with the solution.